# Return maximum value from the array instead of not a number value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, median

I have an array which contains float values as well as NaN value. I am taking median of this array. In current scenario median could be some value or NaN. My question is, if the median is NaN it should return maximum value from the array instead of NaN.

Example of array,

```
x = np.array([NaN,NaN,0.1,0.002,0.14,NaN,NaN,NaN])
```

in this array np.median is NaN. When median is NaN then it should return maximum value from the array, I mean it should return (0.14) value from the array.

How can I return this value?

Comment: Why don't you just test whether the median is `NaN`, and if it is get the maximum? What's the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need maximum value from array instead of NaN. Because I am making a plot with median values. That's why it should return median or maximum value from the array.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I understand what you want, what I would like to know is *what have you tried*, and where exactly did you get stuck? It seems like trivial functionality, and yet you've apparently made no effort to implement it.

Comment: nan stands for Not A Number, and this is not equal to 0. Median of a array is the middle value of a sorted array.So how is it possible to sort a array that contains nan value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import NaN

x = np.array([NaN,NaN,0.1,0.002,0.14,NaN,NaN,NaN])

def getMedian(arr):
    med = np.median(arr)
    if np.isnan(med):
        return np.nanmax(arr)
    else:
        return med

print getMedian(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For any operations you need to exclude NaN from to get the answer you are after create a second array that only holds the relevant values and use that array to find the answer.

workinglist = []
for item in x
    if item != NaN:
        workinglist.append(item)

Comment: Can you give me some example ? Thanks